# Should I include unused parameters for consistency?

Tags: c

This question can be abstracted to other programming languages, it is more of an etiquette / style question. Therefore I am expecting some opinions in the answers. But in the responses I would like to see justifications as to WHY one approach is cleaner than another.

I have a module that is somewhat large. It is parser for a proprietary serial communication protocol. In this module I have 40-50 similar functions. They all take similar arguments. When I receive a valid packet and remove all of its framing I will call one of these functions based on the function code of the packet.

So, for argument's sake here is a declaration:

```
/*!
 * \brief Processes an incoming foo packet and updates the bar data structure
 * \param     data_len Length of the packet's data payload
 * \param[in] p_data   Pointer to the packet's data payload
 */
static bool_t process_foo_response(uint8_t data_len, uint8_t * p_data);
```

Now, for some packets I never expect to receive any data payload. The data length is always 0 and no payload is ever checked. I have no purpose or use for the data_len or p_data parameters. I have included these parameters in the parameter list for every function just for consistency so that all functions would have the same common interface. But is that misleading - would it be best to not have those unused parameters at all? I am having trouble deciding if this is the cleanest and most straight forward way to do things, or if I am going to confuse the next programmer in a few years.

When I have an usused parameter, I generally call that out in the param list documentation like this

```
/*!
* \param     data_len This packet has no payload, a payload length of 0 is verified.
* \param[in] p_data   This packet has no payload, so no payload will be processed by
                      this function.
*/
```

One reason I initially wanted to keep all of the parameters there was for the upstream logic - I was thinking of creating a list of function pointers w/ various offsets based on the function code. This way it wouldn't need to be a two dimensional array with pointers to arguments lists. But my upstream logic is now just a big inefficient switch/case (maybe one day I'll be able to justify taking the time to make it fancier and more efficient) but hey this approach is very simple and it was quick to implement!

Comment: I think, having a common type of function pointers is a strong argument for having unused arguments. Another one might be, that you could imagine a function that doesn't have a payload now might have one in the future (optionally maybe). In either cases I would suggest to explicitely check for `data_len == 0` in these functions

Comment: I generally did always check to make sure the length was 0, but I didn't do it 100% of the time. So I have some \todo list items to go back and add that check on a few of the functions.

Comment: Consider `static bool_t process_foo_response0(void) { return process_foo_response(0, NULL); }` instead of the general code calling with unused parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that bothers me about extra parameters is that there is extra room for error: when there are no arguments there is no way that the user can call the function with the wrong arguments but with the ignored arguments the user can pass a buffer length that is non-zero expecting something to happen but your code will still ignore it.

One thing you can do is to use assertions in your functions that expect the payload to be empty, instead of just blindly assuming that the payload is zero.

Another thing you could do on top of that is providing two separate versions of the function. One without the arguments, intended for manual use and one with them, intended for consistency.

Comment: Let me edit my OP. I am not blindly assuming that the payload length is 0 - I check that. But I do not verify that the payload pointer is NULL, Perhaps that would be an improvement.

Comment: I agree with your point. The bigger danger here is assuming that something is working when it isn't. The most preferable thing that could happen if someone uses a function incorrectly would be to throw a compiler error. But if I can't do that then the next best thing would be to throw a runtime error that will get caught early in testing.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the same thing I was thinking. If you include the appropriate assertions, the only big downside is that error checking gets moved to runtime and that the programmer might need to do some extra typing. Its a minor tradeoff of programmer inconvenience for flexibility+consistency and you can always provide two versions of the function if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 3):

In strict C, while you may omit parameter names in function *declarations*, you **must** have parameter names in function *definitions*. Contrast to C++, where parameter names *can* be omitted in definitions.

A common practice for dealing with unused function parameters (since many compilers warn about unused parameters) is to cast the parameter to `void`, usually through a macro:

```
#define UNUSED_PARAMETER(p) ((void)(p))
```

This silences the "unused parameters" warnings, but doesn't produce any additional code.

---

As far as whether to omit the names in the declarations, I'd consider it a trade-off. Keeping the names in the declaration keeps it consistent with the definition, but removing them from the declaration helps enforce the fact they're unused.

Comment: In that case it would probably be even better to just rename it unused_param to further discourage someone from making a faulty assumption that the function does something with that parameter.